# How to generate ER diagram from sql script Reverse Engineering

Tags: sql-server, database, reverse-engineering, entity-relationship, lucidchart

I want to generate an ER diagram through Lucidchart with ER notations (Conceptual ER Diagram)

I am facing troubles applying the steps of importing the sql script into the Lucidchart.

Does anyone know how does the reverse engineering process exactly works working with sql server?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Hh7Z-TT2jc

Comment: Please share more details on what you've tried, what you have so far. Screenshots would be welcome.